# Wikipedia embedded in WinForms App Tutorial

Tags: .net, winforms, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Can anyone post a tutorial here on how to show a Wikipedia article in a .NET WinForms application (C# or VB)? If the article can be placed in a string it suffices, there`s no need to put it on any control.

I found some information on [Wikipedia's API](http://wikipedia-lab.org/en/index.php/Wikipedia_API). After reading it, I added the reference to web service but can`t find a way to make this work.

And if it's possible, explain how images are downloaded from wiki (link or image itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is to the ontology API, it does not include access to the pages.

You can use the [Wikipedia API](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) (self documented). It says there that you can also choose a format from json, jsonfm, php, phpfm, wddx, wddxfm, xml, xmlfm, yaml, yamlfm, rawfm, txt, txtfm, dbg, dbgfm .

- [Example for Images in XML format](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=images&titles=Qatar)
- [Example for the Full page](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Qatar&export)

Does it need to be live Wikipedia articles from the web?

You can download all of Wikipedia from their [database download page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_database), it includes SQL and XML versions.

Comment on this reply if you need more clarifications, What do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

There is also a framework (DotNetWikiBot) for working with MediaWiki wikis (such as Wikipedia) which might have what you need.

http://dotnetwikibot.sourceforge.net